# Auto Increment selection SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a column named `id` in my SQLite database which is auto-increment, Primary Key, Unique.

Is the result of the following query guaranteed to be the smallest value of `id` in the database and does this correspond to the "oldest" (as in a FIFO)  row to be inserted?

```
SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `select min(id) from from table` since AUTOINCREMENT only guarantees to have ROWIDs that have never been used before by the same table in the same database. And to be monotonically increasing.

Answer (score 2):

The SQLite [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) is quite explicit:

> **If a SELECT statement that returns more than one row does not have an
>   ORDER BY clause, the order in which the rows are returned is
>   undefined.** Or, if a SELECT statement does have an ORDER BY clause,
>   then the list of expressions attached to the ORDER BY determine the
>   order in which rows are returned to the user.

The `LIMIT` is applied *after* an `ORDER BY` would be, so I don't think it affects the application of this statement.

Hence, if you want the first row, use `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;
```

Note that if `id` is a primary key, this will add basically no overhead.

I should emphasize that *in practice* you are probably going to get the smallest id without the `ORDER BY`.  However, it is a really, really bad idea to depend on behavior that directly contradicts the documentation.

Comment: The docs seem to indicate that in the absence of an `order by` clause the order of the **returned** rows will be undefined. But if the limit is 1, does that necessarily mean that the order that the db is parsed to return that 1 row is undefined?

Comment: @AlexEshoo . . . You would have to assume that `limit` takes on some magical function of returning the row with the lowest `id`, when the query without `limit` has no such guarantees.

Comment: skip the `order by` and `limit` and just use `min()` if you want the first row of id.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the result of the following query guaranteed to be the smallest value of id in the database

Yes. However if the table is empty or the `id` column is NULL, it could also return NULL

> and does this correspond to the "oldest" (as in a FIFO) row to be inserted?

No, there's no guarantee of that.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the `id` key is also NOT NULL. Could you provide a case where the smallest value of `id` would not be the "oldest" row to be inserted? Does the auto-increment lapse and restart from 0 eventually?

Comment: Well, there' are many cases where the smallest 'id' would be the oldest record, but you need to read the source code of everything that inserts into that table to see what it does. If all your inserts are using the auto incremented value generated by sqlite, then as far as I know, the lowest id should be the oldest record.

But nothing stops you from deleting the row with id=1 and then inserting a new rows that has id=1

Comment: In my case I am writing the application that is the sole writer to the database so I can control how things are written. I didn't include that in the question so you are right in general.